# Serial Port Coin Acceptor programming c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I've made a program for coin acceptor.An electronic circuit is connected to coin acceptor and circuit is connected to serialport.I'm using this code to catch pin changes :

```
private void serialPort1_PinChanged(object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
        {
            if(serialPort1.DtrEnable==true)
            {
                if(serialPort1.DsrHolding==true && sayac==true)
                {
                    sure=sure+(60*40);
                    f2.sure2 = sure;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works fine.Every coin gives 40 minutes but sometimes swallows the coin and doesn't give 40 minutes.How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you explain bit more about what do you mean "sometimes swallows the coin" ? Did you expected the DTR to be false?

Comment: "sure" variable keeps remaining time in seconds.Every coin inserted , this function adds 40 minutes to time variable.There is timer in program and every timer tick "sure" variable is decreased 1 second.When i insert coin , function works and adds 40 minutes.But sometimes nothing happens when i insert coin.I want this function to work all time.But it doesn't work sometimes and coin is wasted.

Comment: From your question, you haven't narrowed this down to whether it's a code problem or an electronics problem, so is unanswerable as a code question

Comment: though from a debugging point of view, Log the pin changed event on the first line of your function.  You do have a number of conditions that may be preventing the timer to increase

Comment: I've tested a computer for 5-6 hours. I've inserted coin, but never wasted coin. I've tried this test several times but there was no problem. But i have 35 computers and this computers wastes 10-15 of 100-150 coins everyday. This coin system works %90 true. I want it work %100 properly. İdle computer never fails, but working computer wastes %10. I think this is cods problem or windows problem. Maybe windows can't handle two programs work together. Maybe program is lagging while windows is busy with a game.

Comment: Today I've added some codes to my program. Every timertick, program will check if the serialport is open and if not open, make it open. And also check for dtr enabled to make it enable if false. Tomorrow i will try this. Logging is also good idea. I will also try this if first step fails. Thnx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is using an external device to change the state of a serial port pin, test the electronics on their own and very that it outputs correctly every time.

I would also test the app by manually triggering the serial port pins. 
This link has good info on pin state logic:
http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/techdoc/matlab_external/ch_seri7.html